# Strange extra DIV height in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, css-position

I have two DIVs:

- first one is narrow and is floated left and displays a kind of vertical tab structure.
- second one displays content per selected item in the left DIV

You can see a simplified example [here on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rC93u/6/).

As shown in example, left DIV is usually higher than the right one. That's why the right DIV is vertically shifted down to align it to the bottom of the selected item in the left DIV so the content is always *in view* when a user selects an item on the left.

Everything works as expected in Firefox and IE but not in Chrome.

### Chrome issue

Whenever you select an item in the left DIV that should reposition the right DIV, the whole container of both gets higher even though non of the contained DIVs is as heigh.

**What seems to be going on here and what am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set ur right side div container to position: absolute (i.e height of right and left container to be same and set width as your own)

Comment: Why would I set equal heights to left and right container? That would basically keep right container's content at the top even when user scrolled down to select some lower item in the left container... There would be a lot of scrolling then...

Comment: And what do you mean by: *set width as your own*?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the extra height that is added by using `.container { overflow-y: hidden; }`

Comment: Alternatively, you could set the `marginTop` of the right content instead of the `top`, this also prevents this behaviour in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/rC93u/7/

Comment: `marginTop` is a much better solution than setting `overflow-y` because the latter isn't a valid CSS setting in CSS 2.1